# Google Таблицы - Ошибка при выполнении функции

Tags: google-spreadsheet

Вот функция:

```js
function sumForProduct(code, week) {
  const idMainSheet = "...{some_id}...";
  
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(idMainSheet);
  const listPrice = ss.getSheetByName("...{some_name}...");
  const data = listPrice.getDataRange().getValues();

  const idxCode = data[0].indexOf("code");
  const idxCount = data[0].indexOf("count");
  const idxPrice = data[0].indexOf("price");
  const idxWeek = data[0].indexOf("week");

  let idxString = -1;

  for (let i = 2; i < data.length; i++) {
    if (data[i][idxWeek] === week && data[i][idxCode] === code) {
      idxString = i;
      break;
    }
  }

  const count = Number(data[idxString][idxCount]);
  const price = Number(data[idxString][idxPrice]);

  return count * price;
}
```

Через консоль все работает, когда хочу вызвать как формулу в таблице: `=sumForProduct($D6;E$4)`, то появляется ошибка: `Exception: You do not have permission to call SpreadsheetApp.openById. Required permissions: https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets (строка 4).`, как получить разрешение на использование openById?

Comment: Да, интересно. А что у вас за веб-страница, когда вы переходите по ссылке, указанной в ошибке? У меня пустая веб-страница с надписью "spreadsheets".

Comment: Советую также обратиться в поддержку гугла. Обычно помогает.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Разработчики запретили использовать `SpreadsheetApp.openById()` в пользовательских функциях.
Из документации [Пользовательские функции в Google Sheets](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions?hl=ru), подраздел [Передовой](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions?hl=ru#advanced):

> Невозможно открыть другие электронные таблицы ( SpreadsheetApp.openById() или SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl() ).

И, далее:

> Если ваша пользовательская функция выдает сообщение об ошибке You do not have permission to call X service. , служба требует авторизации пользователя и поэтому не может использоваться в пользовательской функции.

В английском SO описан [один из способов обхода такого ограничения](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63879205/formula-works-in-google-app-script-console-but-returns-authentication-error-in).

Comment: Если возможно сделать перевод ответа, то было бы неплохо его сделать, с указанием авторства оригинального ответа

Comment: @Acinit, по-моему, указание авторства не обязательно. В справке сказано, что ответ принадлежит тому, кто его перевел.